# Fisher information for Laplace Distribution

Tags: statistics, fisher-information

Assume you have $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ *iid* with the below *pdf* and let $x_i$ be the observations of the random variable $X_i$.

I am doing some revision on fisher information functions and I stumbled upon a problem asking to derive the expected information for a Laplace distribution with *pdf* given by $$f(x;θ)=\frac{1}{2θ}\exp(-\frac{|x|}{θ}) $$

I derived the log likelihood function as $$l(θ)=-n\log(θ)-\frac{\Sigma|x_i|}{θ}-n\log2 $$

$$l'(θ)=\frac{-n}{θ}+\frac{\Sigma|x_i|}{θ^{2}} $$

and $$l''(θ)=\frac{n}{θ^{2}}-2\frac{\Sigma|x_i|}{θ^{3}}$$ and since $E|x_i|=0$ 
I get that the fisher information is $$-\frac{n}{θ^{2}}$$ which is obviously wrong since it cannot be negative. Any tips on what I have done wrong would be appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT: $E|x_i|=0$ this expectation was wrong**

Comment: Your log-likelihood function is wrong, just take the log of the pdf. The expected information doesn't contain any measurements (what I assume the $x_i$ are).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I should have been clearer. You have a bunch of iid RVs with that pdf. I have added an extra comment. Do you still think the pdf is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Ah right ok. In this case we are discussing fisher observed information rather than fisher expected information. It's very important to make that distinction. Can you also add into the question that the $x_i$ are observations of the $X_i$, this just makes it all very clear.

Comment: added, apologies!

Comment: Why do you say $E|X_i|=0$? That would only be possible if $X_i=0$

Comment: That was the mistake. EHH added a great answer below that derives it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$f(x;θ)=\frac{1}{2θ}exp(-\frac{|x|}{θ})$$

then $$l(\theta):=\log f(x;θ) = -\log2 - \log\theta - \frac{|x|}{\theta}$$
$$\frac{\partial l(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = -\frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{|x|}{\theta^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} = \frac{1}{\theta^2} - 2\frac{|x|}{\theta^3}$$ then for each measurement the expected information is,
$$I_\theta = E_{X|\theta}[-\frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}] = E_{X|\theta}[2\frac{|x|}{\theta^3}-\frac{1}{\theta^2}] \\ = \frac{2}{\theta^3} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,\theta) |x|~dx - \frac{1}{\theta^2} \\=\frac{2}{\theta^3} \int\limits_{-\infty }^\infty  \frac{1}{2θ}exp(-\frac{|x|}{θ}) |x|~dx - \frac{1}{\theta^2}\\ = \frac{1}{\theta^4}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty  exp(-\frac{|x|}{θ}) |x|~dx- \frac{1}{\theta^2}\\ = \frac{2}{\theta^4} \int\limits_0^\infty exp(-\frac{x}{θ}) x~dx - \frac{1}{\theta^2} \\ (integrating ~  by ~  parts)= \frac{2}{\theta^4} \theta^2 - \frac{1}{\theta^2}  \\ = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$$

Then for independent measurements the expected information simply adds and so because they are iid, from measurments of $X_1,...,X_n$ the expected information in then,

$$
nI_\theta = \frac{n}{\theta^2}
$$

Comment: I see where I was wrong now. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x, \theta) = \frac{1}{2 \theta} \exp (- \frac{|x|}{\theta})$ then $$\partial_\theta \log f(x, \theta) = 2 \exp \Bigl(\frac{|x|}\theta\Bigr) \cdot \theta \cdot \Bigl(-\frac{\exp (- \frac{|x|}{\theta})}{2\theta^2} + \frac{\exp (- \frac{|x|}{\theta})|x|}{2 \theta^3}\Bigr) = \frac{|x|-\theta}{\theta^2}$$

and thus $$f(x, \theta) (\partial_\theta \log f(x, \theta))^2 = \exp\Bigl(-\frac{|x|}\theta\Bigr) \cdot \frac{(|x|-\theta)^2}{2 \theta^5}.$$

The integral in definition of Fisher information is easy to calculate, as

$$\int \exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}\theta\Bigr) \cdot \frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2 \theta^5} \,\textrm{d}x = \exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}\theta\Bigr) \cdot \frac{\theta^2+x^2}{2 \theta^4},$$

notice the missing absolute value here.

Comment: Why are you using $(\frac{\partial \log f}{\partial \theta})^2$? It's meant to be the expected value of the second derivative, not the first derivative squared.

Comment: @EHH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information says that I am right, read the paragraph starting with "The second moment is called the Fisher information...", please.

Comment: You're right! Thanks I hadn't seen that it can also be determined this way before.

Comment: But I'm not sure that your derivative there is right, just having a look myself.

Comment: This can't be right, taking logs removes the exponential but your derivative still has them.

Comment: I've added a clarification, @EHH.

Comment: Ah yes I see now, but I still think the answer is wrong because we have taken expected value w.r.t $x$, hence $x$ cannot be in the final solution. The integral needs to be between limits for expected value and I think this might be the issue.